# Under stairs stale air/damp/mold smell

Tags: ventilation

We have a stale air/damp/mould smell coming from the under stairs cupboard which you can smell around the ground floor area.

The floor boards aren't damp, neither is the wood of the stairs from below.

Underneath the floorboards there are lots of pipes and wires and I can see the earth below which looks like cement and gravel.

The pipes have condensation on them, but it seems like it's not coming up as the floorboards seem dry.

What's the best way of stopping the smell? Do I just need to ventilate it or should I try and tackle the source of the smell?[image]

Comment: I presume that this pic is taken through a removable access hatch so you can get to that valve. Or, is the entire floor open?

Comment: Just a hatch to get to the tap

Answer (score 1):

The problem is cold water coming into the house which makes the metal pipe cold. Warm air from inside then condenses on the pipe. A little more heat and ventilation might fix this. Some folks add pipe insulation to the cold pipe and extra ventilation never hurts. The ground under the pipe looks damp in the photo. Not sure of the area or access, but sliding polythene under the whole area (on the ground), might help if any of the moisture is coming up from the ground.

Comment: I'd agree that the pipes are definitely sweating and that's a leading candidate for the dampness causing the smells. Insulating the pipes is the best place to start, but man, that could be a tough one if that crawl space is as tiny as it seems to be!